# Responsive without a viewport (Within a frame)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, frames

I'm currently doing a god awkward job for a client in which they own a domain but can't move the DNS due to them currently using the MX. Anyways, their wanting a website built and pointed to that domain. Unfortunately the service doesn't have any webspace and only allows me to forward towards to another host as a redirect. Which either brings who the host address is so that's not an option or within a frame, which breaks all the media queries for the site and doesn't allow mobile view. Frame doesn't response to viewport. Also masking doesn't appear to respond with the current host so that's out the question too.

I'm currently using bootstrap so using serverside mobile detection isn't a quick option.

So I'm wondering how the best course of action is. The site is already fully designed, so I'm really looking for a way to get frames to detect viewport and allow media queries to work.

Comment: You mean an iFrame, not frames , don't you?

Comment: No, unfortunately I mean the frame tag, as in frameset.
I am aware this is highly deprecated but it is the situation I've been given,

Comment: I'm sure your answer is "no" here, but couldn't you manipulate just the A name records?

Comment: And/or MOVE the DNS, but point the MX to the current location. This really seems like an issue of working with your DNS, and insisting that this is needed. A site within a frame also breaks all kinds of usefulness inherent to websites, such as links.

Comment: Unfortunately it's an all or nothing situation, the domain doesn't allow for both DNS and MX records to be pointed to different servers.

Comment: Okay I managed to get through to the company and moved the DNS but kept the MX. So yeah, until DNS propagation completes I'll not fully know but emails seem to still work.